# MySQL Where IN with an Array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, where-in

I've searched a bit but haven't found exactly what I'm looking for, so far. Basically I have a MySQL database with a couple tables (`keywords`, `company` and `link` tables).  I want to be able to supply an array of keywords and find the associated companies. When I run the second query without the `WHERE IN` clause, it works. When I supply an array, it doesn't.

```
select  keywords.idkeywords into @keyId
from keywords where
keywords.keyword IN ('Entertainment', 'Public');

select distinct company.company_name
from keywords, keyword_to_company, company 
where keyword_to_company.keywordId = @keyId
  and keyword_to_company.compId = company.idcompany;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query just doesn't make sense.  First, you are trying to put multiple values in `@keyid`, but you can't do that.  And, MySQL doesn't have the concept of table variables.  You *could* use a temporary table.

Then the second query is worse.  Does this query work for you?

```
select distinct c.company_name
from keywords k natural join
     keyword_to_company k2c natural join
     company c
where k.keyword IN ('Entertainment', 'Public') and
      k2c.compId = company.idcompany;
```

I'm only using `natural join` because you don't specify the `join` keys.  In general, you should always specify the columns being joined, using either `on` or `using`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...
Your query didn't work..

### This query does work however.  Althought @keyId returns multiple rows, the query succeeds and results in a listing of associated companies.  i agree that it shouldn't work, but it does.

select  keywords.idkeywords into @keyId  from keywords where
keywords.keyword = 'Entertainment' 
and
keywords.keyword = 'Public';

select distinct company.company_name from keywords, keyword_to_company, company 
where

```
keyword_to_company.keywordId = @keyId
```

and 
    keyword_to_company.compId = company.idcompany;